# Symfony - Overwriting a default configuration setting in YAML

Tags: symfony1, yaml

I am trying to overwrite the config setting sf_app_template_directory within my frontend application.

I can do it from within my controller, like this:

```
sfConfig::set('sf_app_template_dir', 'somewhere else');
```

However, I'm not sure about the exact syntax to perform this from within my YAML configuration.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it in the project configuration (or frontend-specifically if needed). The example here explains exactly what you're looking to do:

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_sub_customizing_the_file_structure